# Can not find web element using selenium because xpath's index is not same as browser

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

#### `selenium` can not find element using xpath.

---

if i send xpath to `selenium`.
it can not found element.

i found reason is my xpath is not proper to `selenium`.

- *my_xpath* : `/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]`.

  - can not found element.
- *edit_xpath* : `/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]`.

  - found element.

the differences between 2 paths is *index*.
*my_xpath*'s index is *[3]* and *edit_xpath*'s index is *[2]*.

#### but when i use `parsel` library. it found element using *my_xpath*.

my wondering is what is the differences between `selenium` and `parsel`.
is that about *JS rendering*? or *interactive web*?
i have no clue.. and how can i handle this?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the page that you are scraping it off? Are you also sure that there are no duplicate elements on the page? Hard to tell why one works and the other doesn't, though i suspect its likely to do with some errors on your end.

Comment: When you use `parsel` do you fetch the HTML in a different way or do you use  Selenium 's `browser.page_source`?

Comment: @wp78de  yes i use Selenium's `browser.page_source`.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 i am sorry about not produce url. my target website's `robots.txt` do not allow scrape data so i think this is kind of illegal. maybe that is error yes.. but i do not know why.